# Get all records between first and last row, satisfying condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to select all rows, starting from the first row, satisfying the condition, up to the last row, satisfying another condition. If no row satisfies the second condition, I need all the remainng rows. I've come up with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE ID BETWEEN
(
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM History  WHERE 
{FirstCondition} AND {GeneralCondition} ORDER BY ID ASC
) AND (
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM History WHERE 
{SecondCondition} AND {GeneralCondition} ORDER BY ID DESC
) AND {GeneralCondition}
```

Hovewer it does not select anything, the second condition isn't satisfied by any row. My question is this even possible with a single query? Or should I do the further sorting on application side?

Example:
Need to select all rows for `OrderID=4`(GeneralCondition), strating with the `UserID=3`(FirstCondition) up to `UserID=6`(SecondCondition)

Table

```
     Case 1:                Case 2:
ID|OrderID|UserID      ID|OrderID|UserID
-----------------      -----------------
1 |   4   |  4         1 |   4   |  4
2 |   4   |  3         2 |   4   |  3
3 |   4   |  4         3 |   4   |  4
4 |   4   |  6         4 |   4   |  7
5 |   4   |  4         5 |   4   |  4
6 |   5   |  4         6 |   5   |  4
7 |   5   |  4         7 |   5   |  4
```

Desired output:

```
     Case 1:                Case 2:
ID|OrderID|UserID       ID|OrderID|UserID
-----------------       -----------------
2 |   4   |  3          2 |   4   |  3
3 |   4   |  4          3 |   4   |  4
4 |   4   |  6          4 |   4   |  7
                        5 |   4   |  4
```

Comment: Please show sample data as a table, as a minimal example, and the expected output.

Comment: have you run the subselects on their own? what do they return?

Comment: What is secondCondition?  Do you have data that matches it?

Comment: Subselects return what they should return. Second subselect returns NULL if no row satisfies condition, so that the main select selects noting, as it compares ids with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM History WHERE ID BETWEEN
(
    SELECT MIN(ID) FROM History WHERE {FirstCondition} AND {GeneralCondition}
) AND (
    IIF
    (
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM History WHERE {SecondCondition} AND {GeneralCondition}) IS NOT NULL,
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM History WHERE {SecondCondition} AND {GeneralCondition}),
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM History WHERE {GeneralCondition})
    )
) AND {GeneralCondition}
```

Here a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47df3/5)

Comment: Yes! That IIF function is what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: in case if only one value match both condition in that case MIN(ID) will be equal to MAX(ID) and above query will return only one row.  it seems the below requirement will not be met by this query- If no row satisfies the second condition, I need all the remainng rows

Comment: @RahulRichhariya FirstCondition and SecondCondition are mutually exclusive, but that is a good point

Answer (score 1):

Conditonal aggregate  may have a better plan

```
SELECT * 
FROM History 
WHERE ID BETWEEN
    (
        SELECT MIN(ID) FROM History WHERE {FirstCondition} AND {GeneralCondition}
    ) AND 
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN {SecondCondition} THEN ID END) IS NULL 
              THEN MAX(ID) 
              ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN {SecondCondition} THEN ID END)
              END
        FROM History 
        WHERE {GeneralCondition})
    ) 
    AND {GeneralCondition}
```